# Get and append data problem in CTK, python

Tags: python, user-interface, customtkinter

So I'm writing a program that finds max and min values in you imported list, but when I tried to paste a text using .get() and .insert(), its just not working. The error message that shows on the console said that "insert expected 2 arguments, got 1"

```
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.iconbitmap('/imgs/icon.ico')
root.title("Max - Min finder")

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

list = []
is_there_smth = False
def clearing():
    list_view.delete(0.0, "end")
    list.clear()


def submitting():
    global is_there_smth, get
    get = list_view.get(0.0, "end")
    if is_there_smth:
        list_view.delete(0.0, "end")
        is_there_smth = False
        list.insert(float(enter.get()))
    else:
        is_there_smth = True
        list_view.insert("end", get)
    list.append(float(enter.get()))
    list_view.insert("end", str(enter.get()) + ', ')


def find_max_min():
    global is_there_smth, get
    get = list_view.get(0.0, "end")
    if is_there_smth:
        list_view.delete(0.0, "end")
        is_there_smth = False
    else:
        is_there_smth = True
    list_view.insert("end", "Max:" + str(max(list)) + '\n' + "Min:" + str(min(list)))


label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="List", font=("Monolisa", 20))
label.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

list_view = ctk.CTkTextbox(root, width=250, height=50)
list_view.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

enter = ctk.CTkEntry(root, placeholder_text="Enter each number", font=("Monolisa", 14), width=200)
enter.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

submit = ctk.CTkButton(root, text="Submit", font=("Monolisa", 14), command=submitting)
submit.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

clear = ctk.CTkButton(root, text="Clear", font=("Monolisa", 14), command=clearing)
clear.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

findmax = ctk.CTkButton(root, text="Find max and min", font=("Monolisa", 14), command=find_max_min)
findmax.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
root.mainloop()
```

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to fix

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Add the error that's showing up in your console so that it's easier to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

On line 24, you wrote `list.insert(float(enter.get()))`

If you wanted to insert a value in the list, you should replace this line by `list.insert(index_to_insert_to, float(enter.get()))` and replace index_to_insert_to by the index you want to insert at.

If you wanted to insert text in the textbox, you should replace this line by `list_view.insert(where_to_insert, str(float(enter.get())))` and replace where_to_insert by where you want to insert the text in the textbox.

To summarize, you forgot the index to insert the value at.